# Power BI Error: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Non-null assertion failure"

Tags: powerbi, teradata

I'm trying to open a Power BI file, but I keep receiving the following error message: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Non-null assertion failure". I'm unable to open the file at all.

I am using Power BI Desktop Version 2.109.1021.0 64-bit (September 2022) As it is compatible with the version of Power BI Report Server my company are using.

The file connects to Teradata via Direct Query. Everything was working fine until last night where I can't get into the file due to the error.

Restarted PowerBI Desktop

Cleared the Power-Bi Cache

Restarted Machine

Inspected Teradata fields for Null values in connected tables and can't find anything

Any help would be greatly appreciated!